# Socket Programming c# Window Application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a small application which log data from client to server. I want to get the status of client application when it exit the application from task messenger. How do i get the client status.

Just like in skype.

I user exits skype form task messenger another user's skype shows got logged out this user.

Answer (score 1):

You could have the client send small heartbeats in regular intervals. If those heartbeats stop coming you know that the client has shut down (either the process was killed, the application shut down, the computer shut down, the network connection dropped, etc...).

Comment: Thanks Andreas! The same idea was in my mind. that an another application pinging with all client IP and if any request out, it remain timeout. Is there any fastest way so it will may not slow down the performance of application as well as server.

Comment: Difficult topic! I can only warn about database connections during heartbeats. Make sure you're not locking whole tables, avoid running into deadlocks, etc.

Comment: I did it myself through socket programming. just as in simple chat application.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you catch SocketException and also check for receiving zero bytes. If you receive zero bytes the other side closed the connection cleanly. If you get a SocketException with the SocketErrorCode set to ConnectionReset then you can also assume the other side is gone. The only thing you won't pick up is half open connections. For that you will need some sort of keep alive packet as Andreas suggested.

Comment: SocketException is very unreliable, you will only get it on sending to the client, which you typically don't do (server only responds to client requests). You don't want to maintain connections open, there are only so many concurrent connections you can have

Comment: @Andreas. Not at all. I get it plenty on socket.Receive() methods. Also in some protocols either the client or the server may initiate the keep alive packet. If requests are responded to in asyncronous fashion the the server will initiate the communication.

Comment: I have done through Socket socketForClient = tcpListener.AcceptSocket(); to get the diconccected computers handled in exception. Anyways thanks for your comments.